# How to create a loop that ask the user for two numbers, one will be for the length of the array, and the other for how many times the loop iterates

Tags: c#, arrays, monodevelop

```
  public static void sortInterations()
    {
        Random r = new Random (); 
        Console.WriteLine ("Please enter the number of items in the array that will be sorted:");
        int numitems = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
        int[] arrayOfInts = new int[numitems];
        Console.WriteLine ("Please enter a number for iterations:");
        int iterations = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

        TimeSpan runningTime;

        for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++) 
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < arrayOfInts.Length; count++) 
            {
                arrayOfInts [count] = r.Next (numitems);
            }
        }
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        selectionSort (arrayOfInts);
        runningTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);
        Console.WriteLine ("Time for ___ sort to complete: " + runningTime.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.ffffff"));
        sortInterations ();


   }
```

This is what i have so far! Basically i want to fill the array with random numbers and then sort it using bubble sort the number of times that the user entered in for the variable iterations and then prints out how long it took.

Comment: these are the exact instructions: Create a for loop that iterates num_i times.

In the body of the loop,

Create an array of n random integers

Get the time and set this to start-time. You will have to figure out what the appropriate command is in the programming language you are using to find them time

Use bubble sort to sort the array

Get the time and set this to end-time

Subtract end-time from start-time and add the result to running_time

Comment: And your question is? What _specifically_ do you need help with? What is your code doing now, and what do you want it to do instead? Please see [ask] for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. In the meantime, I'll point out that in a language like C#, using tail recursion to loop on the logic in a method is a pretty poor practice; you should just wrap the method body in a `while` loop instead.

Comment: I dont really have a question, I'm just trying to see if i implemented the instructions correctly

Comment: The instructions seem to have a flaw. Example, the user enters how many items are in the array. Then the user enters the number of iterations? What if the user enters less iterations than are needed to sort the array? Or if the array is sorted should you continue iterating through the array even if it is already sorted? Example user enters and array size of 20, then enters 1 iteration? Depending on the type of sort method you use I am confident it will take more than 1 iteration to completely sort the array. These instructions seem to create a conflict in what the user could possibly input.

Comment: The application is supposed to sort an array of random numbers  and do that based on the number inputted by the user in the iterations variable and then put the time it used to complete that

Comment: the interations that will be entered will be 100, 1000,10000. and the array size will be 50, 250, and 500

Comment: I am not sure why you would have the user enter the number of iterations because this will be determined by HOW you sort it, the number of elements to sort and its sorted condition to begin with.

Comment: No, the iterations variable determines how many times the for loop will sort the array of random numbers

Comment: Ah… the iteration is the number of different randomly generated arrays of the size the user entered. I took iteration to mean how many times to go through the array, instead of how many random arrays to create. From what you have, it looks like your inner “for” loop creates the random arrays, but that’s it. When you exit the inner “for” loop you are not doing anything with the newly created random array. The selectionSort(arrayOfInts)  is simply going to sort the LAST array. Same with the time… all these are outside your loop. Not sure why you are using recursion here it seems unnecessary.

Comment: i removed the recursion and does that mean i have to put ( DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        selectionSort (arrayOfInts);
        runningTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);) inside of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. You may want to get a new seed on each iteration of creating a new array of random ints to avoid getting the same or close to the same numbers.

```
public static void sortInterations()
{
  Random r = new Random();
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of items in the array that will be sorted:");
  // no checking for invalid input i.e. "aA" will crash here when you try to convert 
  int numitems = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  int[] arrayOfInts = new int[numitems];
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number for iterations:");
  // no checking for invalid input i.e. "aA" will crash here when you try to convert 
  int iterations = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  // loop for each random array
  for (int index = 0; index < iterations; index++)
  {
    // loop to generate an array of random numbers      
    for (int count = 0; count < arrayOfInts.Length; count++)
    {
      arrayOfInts[count] = r.Next(numitems);
    }
    // a random array has been created start the clock and sort it
    Stopwatch elpased = new Stopwatch();
    elpased.Start();
    selectionSort(arrayOfInts);
    elpased.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Sort array Number: " + index + " Time for sort to complete in milliseconds: " + elpased.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```